# QtQuick 2 CheckDelegate set Box side

Tags: qml, qtquick2

So I've set up a simple listView with CheckDelegate but it looks like this:
[image: listView]

I'd like to have the buttons on the left side of the text.
Is this possible through an option or do I need to make a Custom ItemDelegate?

```
//minimal example
ListView {
            model: ["Albert Einstein", "Ernest Hemingway", "Hans Gude"]
            delegate: CheckDelegate {
                text: modelData
            }
        }
```

Comment: It looks that you somehow set right-to-left layout. As I know that could be done or using [QGuiApplication ::layoutDirection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#layoutDirection-prop) or by setting `LayoutMirroring.enabled: true`. Check you source, the default `CheckBox` is `▢ text`. Making custom delegate doesn't make a sense - it defines `indicator` and `contentItem` separately.

Comment: Checkboxes do appear that way, but not the checkdelegate. If you look at the documentation they are that way there as well: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-checkdelegate.html

Comment: I've tried setting both layout directions explicitly on the object(s) with no visual change.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wasn't paying attention that you use `CheckDelegate`, nor `CheckBox`. What if you will change it to `CheckBox`? I guess that `CheckDelegate` use it internally anyway.

Comment: if I use CheckBox as the delegate it only shows the first child, all other get lost somehow. Edit: nevermind, the layout ate it. It seems to work like this. Which raises the question what is CheckBoxDelegate for, am I going to run into issues later?

Comment: I found out what the drawback is. Regular Checkbox does not update from the model. And the model gets pushed in later from outside qml, so it doesn't populate the list anymore.

Comment: I've tested it now and found that `LayoutMirroring.enabled: true` works for `CheckDelegate`. Did you try that?

Comment: That does work. I did not know it exists.

Comment: I tried using the `LayoutMirroring` technique in a  `CheckDelegate` within a `ComboBox` (instead of `ListView`) and couldn't get the expected result. Any clues ?